What could be causing these random, pseudo-blister defects when electroplating galvannealed steel?
We are getting these  small, random, almost pseudo-blister defects when trying to electroplate 1mm thick galvannealed steel. It is occurring about 20% of the time. The rest of the part looks fine but we cant figure out why this keeps happening. It almost looks like its getting ready to blister but isn't quite getting there. Sometimes it happens near weld points, other times it occurs at the edge of the material yet it doesn't occur at ALL the weld points nor does it occur all along the edge. You can see it near the top weld point for the nut but the other 3 weld points are just fine. What is causing it and what measures can be taken to prevent it?

Hydrogen blistering occurs when hydrogen ions are also plated out into the steel electrode. Corrosion frequently causes this blistering (see image, Ref 1).

A lengthy review of hydrogen blistering can be found on the internet (Ref 2). Ah, but this answer is hardly of value unless it includes a way to prevent it. Now that could be problematic, but it seems that there is a possibility because the frequency of occurrence is not 100%.
If the blistering seems to occur at specific points routinely, it would be worth considering if the solution at those points is different: for instance, that surface might be closer to the positive electrode, and therefore more depleted in the metal, and and/or at a lower pH. The surface that blisters might be scratched or poorly galvanized, leading to an easier entry into the steel.
The blistering might be addressable by reducing the time of electroplating to a bare minimum, such that NO blisters can be observed, then removing the steel from the solution and dehydrogenating it by heating. Then replace the steel into the solution and finish up the electroplating. (Tedious, and probably not commercially effective.)
Another possibility would be to modify the plating solution; perhaps increasing the desired metal concentration and/or raising the pH could put the metal onto the steel without putting so much hydrogen into it. But hydrogen will probably still be incorporated into the steel, just not enough to blister it. It will therefore be not as strong as without the hydrogen implantation, but hopefully not significantly.
Ref 1. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hydrogen-blistering-randall-stremmel#:~:text=Hydrogen%20blistering%20is%20a%20type,the%20oil%20and%20gas%20industry.
Ref 2.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1875510022001378
